# Unable to select reCaptchaV2 checkbox in SeleniumBase

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumbase

I have a SeleniumBase code like this

```
from seleniumbase import SB
from func_timeout import func_set_timeout, FunctionTimedOut

def checkbox():
    print('- click checkbox')
    checkbox = 'span#recaptcha-anchor'
    try:
        sb.wait_for_element(checkbox)
        sb.click(checkbox)
        sb.sleep(4)
    except FunctionTimedOut as e:
        print('-  checkbox:', e)
```

When I call `checkbox()` it gives error and the browser crashes quickly without clicking the checkbox

I tried replacing
`checkbox = 'id#recaptcha-anchor-label'`
`checkbox = 'id#rc-anchor-center-item'`
but it didn't work

Comment: Have you considered that reCAPTCHA is designed to prevent *exactly* what you’re attempting to do here…?